# How to I get my page on Ubuntu 14.04 to maximize correctly

Tags: maximized

When I click maximize, It will maximize the window.  However it will leave about a one inch gap between the top and the left side.  How do I get this to go away and make the window maximize fully.  The left side is where I have the launcher bar located.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this an upgraded system or a clean install?  I recommend creating a new user account and testing it while logged in as the new user.  Perhaps there are some config files left over that are causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose using CompizConfig Settings Manager can be of some use for your problem (install it, if you don't have it).

```
     sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager wmctrl
```

Check your present settings using Window Management tab, and change settings for maximize window or look for Snap Window or for Grid features. Try different settings until you get what you need. Check other tabs in CompizConfig Settings Manager for wrong compositing options.

Note: Using CompizConfig Settings Manager can make your system freeze. Change only what it is required for your present needs, and if anything goes wrong revert CompizConfig Settings to default and try again.